# Boltzmann machines - unclamped / negative phase

Tags: neural-networks, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am studying BMs and RBMs. I am right to understood that we model the "free" / or "negative" phase of the model by not clamping the data to any data, but running the model until convergence with a random data-vector and a random set of weights? If everything is random - is the stationary distribution hence purely and only depended on / a function of the number of hidden and visible units and the specific activation function?

Answer (score 0):

No, in the negative phase you use the current weights, biases (not a random set of weights).  So the stationary distribution is only a function of the current weight matrix, biases (and the activation function).

What you're trying to estimate in the negative phase is the distribution of the states (x and h) given the model (which is parameterized by your weights and biases).